# Is it possible to CAST values during SUM queries?

Tags: mysql, casting, sum

I have a simple query to summarise values of column. However for boolean values I'm using ENUM fields, which store all its values as strings and for that reason SUM work incorrectly.
MySQL allows to perform CASTING operation on values during select and ordering but it seems like it does not work for maths functions.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(`tables` AS SIGNED)) AS total FROM event_guests WHERE `event_id`='1923'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's in the `tables` field, literally? a string '0' or a string '1'? If it's just a boolean type, why not use the native MySQL `bit` type?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the casted field in a SQL variable. Then use that variable in your Maths operation.

---

```
SET @v2 = CAST('tables' AS SIGNED);
SELECT (@v1 := CAST(`tables` AS SIGNED)) AS signed_tables, SUM(@v1) AS total FROM event_guests WHERE `event_id` = '1923';
```